# MS SQL Always On is on UNC Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, alwayson

Microsoft writes that you can use Always On on the UNC path, but does not explain.

How to make one replica to \server1\data1, and the second to \server2\data2

Comment: Please elaborate this `How to make one replica to \server1\data1, and the second to \server2\data2`

Comment: Please share the link for this `Microsoft writes that you can use Always On on the UNC path`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/always-on-failover-cluster-instances-sql-server

Comment: @Nikolay - the letters `unc` appear four times on that page, but in all circumstances, as part of a larger word.

Comment: server message block (SMB) file shares - protocol. UNC path - method of connection SMB